# Unable to iterate over retrieved data

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs, angular-promise

I have a function in my `friendsService` which returns an array of objects.

```
getTopFriends: function () {
var deferred = $q.defer();
var data = [];
FB.api('/me/photos/uploaded', function(response) {
    angular.forEach(response.data, function(key, value) {
        FB.api('/' + key.id + '/tags', function(response) {
            angular.forEach(response.data, function(key, value) {
                var res = {
                    id: key.id,
                    name: key.name
                }
                FB.api('/' + key.id + '/picture?width=200&height=200', 'GET', function(response) {
                    res.url = response.data.url;
                    data.push(res);
                });
            });
        });
    });
    deferred.resolve(data);
});
return deferred.promise;
```

}

Then in my controller, I use it like this:

```
friendsService.getTopFriends().then(function(data) {
  console.log(data);
});
```

And I get a response like this, which is to be expected.
[image]

But if I try to iterate over that data using `angular.forEach()`, I get no result or error in console. How do I find out what's the problem in my code and how do I go about fixing it?

Comment: Do you get any js errors when tring to iterate over the data? And also please show the exact code that was not working.

Comment: try accessing any specific field from the response json like data[0].field_name, and see if it displays. Then you can track down what is getting wrong in your forEach loop

Comment: Looks like your response has no data field. You should try to iterate on response and not `response.data`. Hope this hepls

Comment: @MasterMohsin If I try to log `data[0]`, it is undefined.

Comment: Use your object name in the place of 'data', in your case 'response' is the object name

Comment: @MasterMohsin, at any given point in the function, the call to FBI.api() always returns some data. However, that is not the problem. The problem is the custom "data" object that I'm trying to resolve in the promise. It displays the data (screenshot above), however I'm unable to perform any action on it.

Comment: Did this help you?

Answer (score 0):

You are resolving the promise before any of the calls that populate the array have finished.

This means that `data` in the following:

```
friendsService.getTopFriends().then(function(data) {
  console.log(data);
});
```

Will be an empty array.

`angular.forEach()` won't give any errors, but won't do anything since there are no elements.

`console.log` works a bit differently though.

At the top of your screenshot next to the arrow you see an empty array: []

This means that when the `console.log(data)` statement was executed, the array was empty.

In fact, if you hover the `i` with the blue background it will say:

```
Object value at left was snapshotted when logged, value below was evaluated just now.
```

When you clicked in the console to expand and inspect the contents of the array, the array was reevaluated and shown. By this time the api calls were completed and the array populated.

You simply need to move the call to `deferred.resolve(data);` to the most inner callback, and only call it when all the callbacks have finished.

Comment: Since the inner most callback is inside a `angular.forEach()` statement, how would that work exactly? The promise would be resolved in the first iteration and I wouldn't get the rest of the data. Am I correct?

Comment: Yes, that is correct. You need to only resolve if after the last has finished. So with your current design either keep track of count and compare it with the length or use a for loop and index instead of forEach.